# pg_dump failed on standby server canceling statement due to conflict with recovery in postgresql on ubuntu

Tags: postgresql

On my production server sometimes backup failed with below messages. This backup is scheduled on standby node. (In my environment streaming replication is configured.) There is no process running during this backup time. This is a nightly cron job on an Ubuntu machine.

```
2020-07-01 05:21:07.567 CEST [27925] postgres@DBname LOG:  process 27925 still waiting for AccessShareLock on relation 2610 of database 17948 after 1000.096 ms
2020-07-01 05:21:07.567 CEST [27925] postgres@DBname DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 25802. Wait queue: 1559, 27925.
2020-07-01 05:21:17.120 CEST [25802] postgres@DBname ERROR:  canceling statement due to conflict with recovery
2020-07-01 05:21:17.120 CEST [25802] postgres@DBname DETAIL:  User was holding a relation lock for too long.
2020-07-01 05:21:17.120 CEST [25802] postgres@DBname STATEMENT:  COPY public.tablename(id, col1,col2,col3, geom) TO stdout;
2020-07-01 05:21:17.127 CEST [27925] postgres@DBname LOG:  process 27925 acquired AccessShareLock on relation 2610 of database 17948 after 10560.447 ms
```

relation 2610 is `pg_index`.  I tried to lock this table and reproduce the table but didn't get any error.

Has anyone faced this issue? Any hint/fix is appreciated.

Comment: What version are you running?

Answer (score 0):

Somebody is locking the table on the primary server in `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` mode.

Such locks are taken by `VACUUM (FULL)`, `TRUNCATE`, `ALTER TABLE` and similar commands, but can also happen during a regular `VACUUM`, if it decides to truncate empty pages off the end of the table when it is done.
While it is easy to avoid the former statements, autovacuum cannot be avoided, but from v12 on you can set the `vacuum_truncate` storage option to `off` on a table to avoid it.

Anyway, that `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock gets replicated to the standby server, where it conflicts with the `ACCESS SHARE` lock that `pg_dump` has on the table (to read it).

That causes a conflict. I guess that `max_standby_streaming_delay` is set to 10 seconds, so after delaying replication of the lock for 10 seconds, the startup process terminates the query and hence `pg_dump`.

Either take no `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` locks on the primary server, or set `max_standby_streaming_delay` to a higher value.

Comment: Hello Laurenz Albe,

Comment: Hello Laurenz Albe,                                                                                                                                            Thanks for your quick response                                                                                          We do VACUUM  Analyze only, not VACUUM FULL.  We have max_standby_streaming_delay is already set to 30 sec (default).  Due to streaming replication for high availability we can not increase it more. How to do no ACCESS EXCLUSIVE locks on the primary.

Comment: I have added some information to the answer about avoiding such locks.

Comment: `TRUNCATE` was the keyword for me, setting `vacuum_truncate` did not help so replaced it with a `DELETE` and problem solved. thanks!